# Win + E keyboard shortcut stopped working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I've managed to mess up my <kbd>Win</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut, such that it gives me the following error message:

[image]

Is there any way to manually restore this shortcut?

I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What does <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> do?

*Because troubleshooting System Internals is sweet...*

Let's look on an untampered system with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what exactly happens when we do that.

The steps I take:

1. Download and run the program: http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe
2. Accept the EULA, reset the filters and filter anything away that's not interesting.
3. Clean the log, press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and stop capturing afterwards.

This leaves me with a bunch of events (as the folder is being opened, etc...), so we look at the first ones:
[image]

Note that we're only going to look at the **SUCCES** ones:

- **HKCU?** No, current user configuration, too big key.
- **HKCU\Software\...\Explorer?** No, explorer configuration, too big key.
- **C:\Windows\?** No, read because it is the working directory
- **HKCU\Software\Classes?** No, Windows classes, too big key, used to search the next one:
- **HKCR\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}?** No, renaming this has no effect.
- **HKCR\Folder?** *BINGO!*

Seems the contents of that key are way too specific regarding execution,
exploring that key, I would say `opennewwindow` would be the action <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> calls.

Just to verify it, let's adjust the value to `Ivo Flipse`.

Ouch, I just broke my computer...
[image]
*BINGO!*

### How do I solve the problem?

*If Ivo Flipse his problem isn't further along the call stack...*

Set

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow\command\DelegateExecute`

to the default value:

`{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}`

You might want to check the other keys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\`,
they should have the same value as above...

Comment: Really great answer that gave me much insight into the system internals, thanks! In my case I had caused this myself by fiddling in the registry to tweak the right-click-context-menu in the explorer - or so I thought. Once I removed the `LegacyDisable` Flag from the `HKCR\Folder\shell\opennewwindow` key the Win+E shortcut and the pinned-to-taskbar-explorer-logo resumed working :)

Comment: Thank you @SebastianH! I don't know how `LegacyDisable` got into my registry but removing that from opennewwindow did the trick! 

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume most likely it is virus corrupting the .exe file association. I have recently come over a fix of it (By jared: http://jaredheinrichs.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/vista-7-fixexe.txt )

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithProgids]
"exefile"=hex(0):
```

save the above as a text file with .reg extension. Then double-click it.

Comment: Care to add what the easiest way to add these registry keys is?

Comment: save the file as abc.reg, double click it.

Comment: I was trying to tempt you into editing your question ;-) Anyway, I guess I'll have to restart for it to take effect, so I'll report back when I have

Comment: The problem still occurs @bubu, even though I verified that the registry keys are created

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me on **Windows 10**, the issue for me was that the folder **opennewwindow** was missing, I duplicate the **open** folder under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\` in a new folder named *opennewwindow* and it worked.