# Win+E doesn't open Explorer

Tags: windows-10

([This is not the same problem as I am having](https://superuser.com/questions/236716/win-e-keyboard-shortcut-stopped-working) - I don't get any messages, and nothing in the event logs.)

Win + E has stopped opening Explorer.

- I've checked for any keys physically stuck down.
- Rebooted several times  - the issue started a month ago.
- Tried a different keyboard.

Update 14/8/16: Still no joy with this **but** I have noticed that when on the desktop; WIN+E takes me to the first item on the desktop starting with an 'E'. WIN+R for instance takes me to the Recycle bin icon, WIN+D takes me to a file called desktop.ini.

Comment: I assume the keys on the keyboard are working normally, just not in this combination? I also assume you don't have any keyboard mapping tools and that you can open Explorer in other ways?

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. There is a theoretical chance that some app  has mapped the key to something else - I've done a virus scan - but that other thing doesn't do **anything** (or anything I can see!)!

Comment: It may be worth while trying it in safe mode (unlikely to help) but seeing what is loaded in the modern way of doing MSCONFIG... (I think it's in the task bar)

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps check these out as well: [Determining which program trapping which hot key shortcut](http://superuser.com/questions/219629/determining-which-program-trapping-which-hot-key-shortcut), [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows?rq=1)

Comment: Also, look into different keyboard languages/layouts. Maybe this somehow affect the windows key similar as how it can affect the right alt.

Comment: Added further information to the main question... I'm at a loss!

Comment: Does pressing `WinKey` open the Start menu?

Comment: Yes, IIRC. I'm at work at the moment - but I believe it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Update fixed it. I asked that question on Aug 14 2016 and this week (Sep 25) an update to Win 10 - a big one - has magically fixed things. Cheers Microsoft.

"Feature update to Windows 10, version 1607"